# How to create GuzzleHttp api with php getting 404 error?

Tags: php, authentication, guzzle6, guzzle

I have advised working on below guzzle API, I have a token, username, and password, but I don't know from where these class has been called and what will I need to enter in these class **Client()** & **AuthData()**.

```
require '../x_static_libs/guzzle/vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$url="https://errr- 
rewards.calusastorefront. p2motivate.com/client/json.php";
$username='EFDEMO';
$password='EFDEMO';
$client = new Client(['auth' => [$username, $password]]);
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://ef- 
rewards.calusastorefront.p2motivate.com/client/json.php/ 
getMemberAccount');
$res->getStatusCode();
$response = $res->getBody();
echo $response;

the error I am getting
{"statusCode":"Error","error": 
{"errorCode":"400","errorMessage":"Authentication Header ID field must 
match Basic Authentication Username"}}
```